# What is the easiest way to implement a Pinch and Zoom Scroll View?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I'm just wondering what the easiest way is to implement Pinch/Zoom.

Regards

Comment: Read the [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html). Zooming and pinching is one of the core properties of `UIScrollView` of which UI elements (WebView) inherit.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as setting a Maximum zoom scale greater than 1 for your `UIScrollView`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, does that mean I should just add this to the 'viewDidLoad'.... [scrollviewName.maximumZoomScale=2.0] ???